# Determinant of sandwiched square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that $A$ is an $m\times m$ matrix, and $S$ a $m\times n$ matrix. Is it possible for the relation
$$ \det S^{\dagger}A S= \det A \det S^{\dagger}S$$ to hold also for $n\neq m$?

For instace, if $\det A = 0$ is it true that also $\det S^{\dagger}AS = 0$?

Comment: $A$ is invertible, so $\det(A)=0$ is impossible.  Is $M^{\dagger}=M^T$, or what is it? Why is $S$ not appearing?

Comment: $M$ was meant to be $S$, thanks, and $S^{\dagger}$ is the hermitian conjugate of $S$. Also, in the last case clearly $A$ is no more invertible, I was generalizing...anyway I relaxed the assumption directly at the beginning.

Comment: No, but if $\,n\ge m\,$ **and** $\,\det(A)=0\,$ then $\det(S^\dagger AS)=0\;\;$

Comment: @greg Yes, but the reason is rather crude: $\det(A)=0$ means the rank of $A$ is less than $m$, as will be the rank of any product involving $A$, like the $n\times n$ matrix $S^\dagger AS$.

Answer (score 0):

The equality does not hold in general. Consider the following counter-example:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & x
\end{bmatrix}$ and $S=\begin{bmatrix}
y \\
0
\end{bmatrix} .$ Then note that $$
\det (S^{\dagger}AS) = y^2,\quad \det(A)\det(S^{\dagger}S)=xy^2.
$$Picking suitable $x$ and $y$ you can see that the equality does not hold. You can also take $x=0$ if you need a non-invertible example.

Comment: I see, that's very clear. Thank you!